# Android - How to get plain HTML using evaluateJavascript from Webview? JSOUP not able to parse the result HTML

Tags: android, android-webview, jsoup

I am using below code to get HTML but i am not getting plain HTML, it contain non escapes character. I am using JSOUP parser which is not able to parse this HTML.

```
webview.evaluateJavascript(
                        "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
                        new ValueCallback<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                            }
                        });
```

I am getting this html string from above code.

```
"\u003Chtml>\u003Chead>\n    \u003Cmeta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n    \u003Cmeta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n    \u003Clink rel=\"shortcut icon\" href=\"https://www.xyx.com/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n    \u003Clink rel=\"icon\" href=\"https://www.xyx.com/favicon.ico\" type=\"image/x-icon\">\n    \n    \u003Ctitle>Page Not Found! : BJSBuzz\u003C/title>\n\n    \u003C!-- \n\tOpen Source Social Network (Ossn)/script>\u003C/body>\u003C/html>"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use JsonReader to parse the value:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("(function() {return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;})();", new ValueCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(final String value) {
        JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(value));
        reader.setLenient(true);
        try {
            if(reader.peek() == JsonToken.STRING) {
                String domStr = reader.nextString();
                if(domStr != null) {
                    handleResponseSuccessByBody(domStr);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        } finally {
            IoUtil.close(reader);
        }
}
```

});

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
v=StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript(v.substring(1,v.length()-1));
```

`unescapeJavaScript` is from apache commons-lang

So many string processing for android webview, why...
The `removeUTFCharacters` method provided in the previous answer is not clean enough.There still remain stuffs like `\"`.

Comment: This is the real answer. Works perfect !

Answer (score 4):

for remove the UTFCharacthers use this function:

```
 public static StringBuffer removeUTFCharacters(String data) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\u(\\p{XDigit}{4})");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(data.length());
        while (m.find()) {
            String ch = String.valueOf((char) Integer.parseInt(m.group(1), 16));
            m.appendReplacement(buf, Matcher.quoteReplacement(ch));
        }
        m.appendTail(buf);
        return buf;
    }
```

and call it inside the onReceiveValue(String html) like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
String result = removeUTFCharacters(html).toString();
}
```

You will obtain a string with clean html.

Bye,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

```
    webview.evaluateJavascript(
          "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
          new ValueCallback<String>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
                         String value = new Gson().fromJson(value, String.class);
                  }
          }
   );
```

you should convert callback param which is a string conveterd to json,  it should be converted back.